R2DBC MariaDB failover in Spring Boot 3
I want to perform a failover setup for r2dbc mariadb. We are using spring boot 3. I have read in some documents that from spring boot 3 it supports these behaviours.
I am expecting something like below
url: r2dbc:mariadb://localhost:3306,localhost:3307/test

When I tried to perform this, it is giving me exception saying not able to get the connection

https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-r2dbc/issues/11 it is not supported.

see https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-r2dbc?tab=readme-ov-file#failover-behaviour
you need to prefix url connection with the failover behavior needed :
so, something like :
url: r2dbc:mariadb:sequential://localhost:3306,localhost:3307/test


This will work only during start up. I need it when the application is running. I am getting below error when the application is in running mode
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connectionat org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.lambda$getConnection$0
